# Adjusting Fixings Frequency with Quantlib (Python) in Caps/Floors Valuation

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, floor, quantlib, cap

I am trying to value a **4Y Cap** with the following characteristics:

- Index: **EURIBOR 6M**
- Payment Frequency: **Semi-Annually**
- Fixings Adjustment: **Annually**

The problem I am facing when using the **QuantLib** library to value this particular **Cap** in Python is that the payment frequency and the fixings adjustment are different. I wonder if there is a way to indicate it to the `ql.Cap()` object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can indicate that directly into the ql.Cap because the Cap contructor basically just expects an iborLeg and a strike.

You could however build that particular iborleg, ie, half yearly periods but every two periods would have the same fixing date, and then feed that into the cap constructor.

Maybe build the coupons manually with ql.IborCoupon, then feed a list of the coupons into ql.Leg and use that in the ql.Cap constructor.